# trap ERR doesn't work with pipes

Tags: bash

I am try to make a system backup script with `trap "" ERR`. I realized the trap doesn't get called when commands are part of pipes `|`.

Heres are some parts of my code that don't work with `trap "" ERR` ...

```
OpenFiles=$(lsof "$Source" | wc -l)
PackagesList=$(dpkg --get-selections | awk '!/deinstall|purge|hold/ {print $1}' | tee "$FilePackagesList")
```

How can I get this to work without using `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then`, or similar coding ? Because this is the reason I declared a trap this way.

Here is the script  ...

```
root@Lian-Li:~# cat /usr/local/bin/create_incremental_backup_of_system.sh 
#!/bin/bash
# Create an incremental GNU-standard backup of important system-files.
# This script works with Debian Jessie and newer systems.
# Created for my lian-li NAS 2016-11-27.

MailTo="admin@example.com"  # Mail Address of an admin

Source="boot etc root usr/local usr/lib/cgi-bin var/www"
BackupDirectory=/media/hdd1/backups/lian-li

SubDir="system.d"
FileTimeStamp=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
FileName=$(uname -n)
File="${BackupDirectory}/${SubDir}/${FileName}-${FileTimeStamp}.tgz"
FileIncremental="${BackupDirectory}/${SubDir}/${FileName}.gtar"
FilePackagesList="${BackupDirectory}/${SubDir}/installed_packages_on_${FileName}.txt"

# have2do ...
# Backup rotate

MailContent="None"
TimeStamp=$(date "+%F %T")              # This format "2011-12-31 23:59:59" is needed to read the journal
exec 1> >(logger -i -s -t "$0" -p 3) 2>&1   # all error messages are redirected to syslog journal and after that to stdout
trap "BriefExit" ERR        # Provide information for an admin (via sendmail) when an error occurred and exit the script

function BriefExit(){
    rm -f "$File"
    if [ "$MailContent" = "None" ]
    then
        case "$LANG" in
        de_DE.UTF-8)
            echo "Beende Skript, aufgrund vorherige Fehler." 1>&2
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Stopping script because of previous error(s)." 1>&2
        ;;
        esac
        MailContent=$(journalctl -p 3 -o "short" --since="$TimeStamp" --no-pager)
        ScriptName="${0##*/}"
        SystemName=$(uname -n)
        MailSubject="${SystemName}: ${ScriptName}"
        echo -e "Subject: ${MailSubject}\n\n${MailContent}\n" | sendmail "$MailTo"
    fi
    exit 1
}

if [ ! -d "${BackupDirectory}/${SubDir}" ]
then
    mkdir -p "${BackupDirectory}/${SubDir}"
fi

LoopCount=0
OpenFiles=1
cd /
while [ "$OpenFiles" -ne 0 ]
do
    if [ "$LoopCount" -le 180 ]
    then
        sleep 1
        OpenFiles=$(lsof $Source | wc -l)
        LoopCount=$(($LoopCount + 1))
    else
        echo "Closing Script. Reason: Can't create incremental backup, because some files are open." 1>&2
        BriefExit
    fi
done

tar -cpzf "$File" -g "$FileIncremental" $Source
chmod 0700 "$File"

PackagesList=$(dpkg --get-selections | awk '!/deinstall|purge|hold/ {print $1}' | tee "$FilePackagesList")
while read -r PackageName
do
    case "$PackageName" in
    minidlna)
        # Code ...
    ;;
    slapd)
        # Code ...
    ;;
    esac
done <<< "$PackagesList"

exit 0
```

Comment: That's untrue. Failed command substitutions absolutely can trigger an ERR trap.

Comment: Could you consider providing a [mcve] proving all three of your claimed cases? (To be clear, the one I frankly disbelieve is the `journalctl` command).

Comment: ...that said, note that ERR traps are prone to all the caveats ascribed to `set -e` in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: (BTW, consider `printf 'Subject: %s\n\n%s\n' "$MailSubject" "$MailContent"`  instead of `echo -e` -- otherwise, you're both (1) relying on nonportable behavior [that, even when present in bash, can be turned off with runtime or compile-time flags], and (2) expanding backslash substitutions *in the content*, even if they were intended to be literal).

Comment: (As another aside, I'd strongly suggest making `Source` a proper array -- that way you aren't relying on `IFS` being a value that will string-split them on unquoted expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with ERR traps at all, *or* with command substitutions, but with pipelines.

```
false | true
```

returns `true`, unless the `pipefail` option is set.

Thus in `OpenFiles=$(lsof "$Source" | wc -l)`, only a failure in `wc` will cause the pipeline to be considered a failure, or in `PackagesList=$(dpkg --get-selections | awk '!/deinstall|purge|hold/ {print $1}' | tee "$FilePackagesList")`, only a failure in `tee` will cause the command as a whole to be considered failed.

---

Put the command `set -o pipefail` at the top of your script if you want a failure from any pipeline component (as opposed to the last component alone) to cause the command as a whole to be considered failed -- and note the other caveats for ERR traps given in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Please note that the `ERR` trap is normally not inherited by functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in subshells.  You can use `set -o errtrace` to change this behaviour if you want something like `echo $(false)` to trigger the trap.

Comment: Thx for clearing this up. This means without `set -o errtrace` I don't have to check functions to run twice on errors ?.

Comment: @Fred, ...however, to be clear, `echo $(false)` would be triggering the trap *in the subshell* -- it wouldn't cause the main script to execute `BriefExit`, but the subshell executing `false` to do so; the main script would still see the successful exit status of `echo` and continue operation.

Comment: @suleiman, if you mean that the default behavior avoids `BriefExit` recursing due to an error, that would be accurate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Yes.  In my error handling framework, I actually cause the subshell to signal its parent process when an error occurs that has not been handled by the subshell itself.  Some of these things I tend to forget because I have them encapsulated and no longer pay attention to the technical subtleties when writing my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to look at the status for each stage in the pipeline:

```
# cat test_bash_return.bash
true | true | false | true
echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"

# ./test_bash_return.bash
0 0 1 0
```